# Getting undefined when fetching data from server, error illegal invocation

Tags: reactjs, forms, api, express, fetch-api

I'm building a banking application which uses JWT for authentication. After submitting the log-in form the server gives a response but for some reason I'm unable to fetch the data from the server, it keeps giving undefined which is odd as I can clearly see the server is giving a response.

Here is how I'm fetching the data

```
onClick={(event)=>{
                            event.preventDefault()
                            let user={tel, password}
                            fetch('http://localhost:3000/login', {
                                method:'POST',
                                headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                                body:JSON.stringify(user)
                            })
                                .then(response=>(response.json()))
                                .then(data=>localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(data)))
                                .then(navigate('/home'))
                                .then(window.location.reload)
                                .catch(error=>{console.log('error sending data to server')})
                        }}
```

When I don't navigate away from the page, I can see the generated token from the server on a blank page

The API currently handling the post on the express server

```
app.post('/login', (req,res,next)=>{
    let loginuser=req.body
    console.log(loginuser)
    let founduser
    Account.find({tel:loginuser.tel}).exec().then(response=>{founduser=response.lastname})
    if (loginuser){
        Account.find({tel:loginuser.tel}, ['userpassword']).exec().then(response=>{
            //New users will require bcrypt.compare() to log-in
            if(response.length!== 0){
                if(loginuser.password===response[0].userpassword){
                console.log('found user')
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                res.json({token:jwt.sign({lastname:founduser},SECRET)})
                next()
            }
            else{
                console.log('hey! check input')
                res.json({errormsg:'Phone number and password mismatch'})
            }}
            else {
                console.log('user not found')
                res.json({errormsg:'User not found'})
            }
        })
    }
})
```

response from the server

```
{ tel: '0123456789', password: '' }
found user
```

browser console

```
error sending data to server
```

from above something is triggering the error handler for the fetch api, can someone explain why this is so and what I'm doing wrong, any assistance is deeply appreciated

I've tried `return fetch('')`
adding setTimeout() to display the fetched data
I'm using reactjs with node/express.js, ODM by mongoose

Comment: Modify this line of code to check what's actually your error : (`error sending data to server + ${error}`)})

Comment: Error shows illegal invocation

Comment: Sorry, But I have no idea how to solve this error now. maybe some content on internet might help you.

Comment: First time I've encountered this error, there isn't much documentation about this error when i searched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on this line:

```
 .then(window.location.reload)
```

You need to change it to:

```
 .then(() => window.location.reload())
```

`then` method expects a function to be passed in as an argument. When you pass `window.location.reload` directly, you're passing in a reference to the `reload()` method of the `window.location` object. However, the `then` method expects a function to be passed in, so it tries to invoke `window.location.reload()` as a function, which results in the illegal invocation error.

Comment: How did I miss that, thanks a lot, this fixes the issue